# How I can view the deleted records from a sql server table?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008

I need to view the deleted records (rows) from a sql server table, actually I am using this command

```
DBCC LOG(MyDatabase,-1)
```

to view the log, but I don't understand the output format.

Is there any free tool to translate the log file of an SQL server database or any documentation which shows how to interpret the information shown by the command `DBCC LOG`?

I am using SQL server 2008.

**UPDATE**

My objective is not recover the deleted records, I just want to see the deleted records or the delete command executed.

Comment: I found it particularly difficult to do this last time I tried. There are a couple of third party tools but I didn't find them overly good. If you have the logs can you restore them to a copy of your last backup restored to a new database?

Comment: I second MrEdmundo's experience. The log really isn't meant to be used as a backup, or as a way to restore data. It's incredibly hard to decipher and I haven't found any tools that do a very good job of sifting through it. Your best bet is to take the last back up, restore it, and find the differences that way (if possible).

Comment: As a lesson learned maybe add morge tables that hold records after any dml has been run on them. For example create a trigger to capture the row before any update,delete is done and flag the row as being either deleted or updated with a d or a u dml_type_id.

Answer (score 5):

Data you are getting from DBCC LOG are in HEX format and you’ll need to convert them in order to become readable.

You can also try using fn_dblog function to read transaction log but you’ll get pretty much the same results that need to be decoded.

There is also a third party tool [ApexSQL](http://www.apexsql.com/sql_tools_log.aspx) Log that can read transaction log and show all logged commands but it comes with a price.