# Can we check who deleted what from SQL Server 2008

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, windows-server-2008, data-recovery

Someone deleted few rows off a very important table in SQL Server 2008 few weeks back, I wonder if I can check log or something, or if I can recover the rows.

Cheers

Comment: You'd most likely need a tool for reading the log if you want to make sense of it. http://www.apexsql.com/sql_tools_log.aspx may do it for you, there seems to be an eval version on the site.

Comment: If the data is that important, why do they have the permissions to delete it?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can recover the records if you have backups of some kind. If you where logging every action then you should be able to check it out.

And finally, [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4101465/how-i-can-view-the-deleted-records-from-a-sql-server-table) is questioning exactly about same issue. On comments to that questions you can find this [other link on how to read transaction logs](http://sqlfascination.com/2010/02/03/how-do-you-decode-a-simple-entry-in-the-transaction-log-part-1/)

Answer (score 3):

Complementing the previous answer, an easiest way for "next time" that this happens would be to enable [CDC](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb522489%28v=sql.105%29.aspx) to track changes on your tables.

[Here](http://www.simple-talk.com/sql/learn-sql-server/introduction-to-change-data-capture-%28cdc%29-in-sql-server-2008/) is a very good article